# Skype doesn't work through Empathy 3.4 but works in Pidgin

Tags: 12.04, empathy, skype, 32-bit

I'm trying to connect to Skype throught Empathy 3.4 in Ubuntu 12.04 i386 (last update installed)
I installed the pidgin-skype plugin, but there is no bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus protocol in list.
It works fine with Pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I couldn't find an answer yet either. I'm sure it'll be fixed eventually. However I did find a good (if not better) alternative. It's the [skype-wrapper](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ppa). I followed the instructions on the second comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119306/skype-wrapper-on-ubuntu-12-04) and upon finishing I restarted my computer. On my computer it was a little glitchy before I restarted the computer (crashing and such) and then once I restarted and ran the command `skype-wrapper` in the terminal, it worked perfectly. No Skype icon or anything. So I'd give this a shot as it worked for me.

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: Hi. It is good for Unity but not Gnome-shell.

So I reported about this here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/970885

Comment: @KEIII Did you find a better option for Gnome?

Comment: @Eyal No. I use Skype as is now.
Here is bug report about this question - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin-skype/+bug/970885

Comment: Actually, it's working better than I expected- certainly better than using notify-send.

Comment: Looks like it has been committed now and should appear in the repos soon :)