# How do I get Skype Wrapper working?

Tags: skype

I am trying to get to work skype-wrapper on Ubuntu

I tried to follow these steps http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-add-skype-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/

Also I tried to download and install it manually but it doesn't work, nothing just happens when I run skype-wrapper

Can anybody advice me how to solve it?

Answer (score 18):

1. Quit Skype if running
2. Uninstall Skype IF you installed it from the repositories.
3. Reboot
4. Choose your [Skype version (32/64 Bit)](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/) to download and install it
5. Make sure you added the repository `ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa`
6. In terminal console, run

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper python-skype
   ```
7. After that, run in terminal console

   ```
   skype-wrapper
   ```
8. Acknowledge the pop up authorization requests (don't forget to check the boxes to remember the selection)
9. Restart and done!

This is how I got it working.

---

Current 14.04 workaround until the skype-wrapper team fixes their PPA packages for Trusty.

1. Download the Saucy package and install - dont worry, this will not harm your installation since its just a python package

   ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ppa/+files/python-skype_1.0.32.0-1%7Esaucy1_all.deb
   ```
2. Install a prerequisite:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-support
   ```
3. Install the downloaded deb:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i python-skype_1.0.32.0-1~saucy1_all.deb
   ```

Now continue starting from point 1. at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Do what MrMuretto says, and it should work.  However, I wanted Skype to always launch using the wrapper.  To do that, you need to modify /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop (with sudo) and add the line:

```
NoDisplay=1
```

after the line "Terminal=0".  Next, modify /usr/share/applications/skype-wrapper.desktop (with sudo) and remove the line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

This will allow skype-wrapper to launch from dash as a true wrapper.

Comment: echo " + 1 " >> downbeat

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Apparently the "NoDisplay" attribute in a .desktop file means exclude from dash (and probably some other things as well).  If neither had the NoDisplay entry set, I believe you would see 2 identical entries for "Skype".  Either that or only one but it would be unclear which one would start when clicked (the app itself or the wrapper).  By setting the wrapper to display and the Skype app itself to hide (NoDisplay=true or 1), we are making only the wrapper show up in dash as "Skype" (and possibly elsewhere), which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem.

If the steps from above doesn't prove working I made it work by installing [python-wnck](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-wnck) [image: Install python-wnck] package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-wnck
```

I beleve that you can find this package in Ubuntu Software Centre.