# Ubuntu 12.10 skype 4.1 cannot properly run wrapper

Tags: skype

I installed downloaded skype from official website "Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)" and installed it. Then I followed these steps:

> Quit Skype if running
>
> Uninstall Skype IF you installed it from the repositories.
>
> Reboot
>
> Choose your Skype version (32/64 Bit) to download and install it
>
> Make sure you added the repository `ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa`
>
> In terminal console, run
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa`
>   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper python-skype`
>   After that, run in terminal console
>
> *skype-wrapper*
>   Acknowledge the pop up authorization requests (don't forget to check the boxes to remember the selection)
>
> Restart and done!

link to the original answer https://askubuntu.com/a/123304/42591

But sadly none of the functions of Skype Wrapper are working. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to the thread that fixed this problem

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101342):

> I dragged and dropped this version
>
> ```
> skype-wrapper
> ```
>
> from this location `/usr/share/application/`

onto the Launcher.