# How to use skype on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: icons, skype

I installed skype 4.2 but now I can not use it at all.

I can not install the [Skype wrapper](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ppa) or can not get the Skype icon to show in the top right panel.

Right now it is unusable if I close the app window. I need to disable Skype from `htop` and start it all over again.

Does any one know if there is a way to enable the Skype wrapper or show the icon on the panel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the method you're using to install Skype wrapper and also the error messages that you get.

Comment: What exactly is Skype wrapper? I am using Skype on Ubuntu, but I'm not familiar with that. I am also not experiencing the issue you're talking about. Perhaps you can demonstrate what you're talking about in a screenshot?

Comment: @gertvdijk From [www.omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/skype-wrapper-for-ubuntu-gets-updated): *A small third-party tool, Skype-wrapper brings a bunch of Ubuntu-specific features to Skype, including Messaging Menu integration and native notifications for message alerts, and Unity quicklists for quick access to call controls.*

Comment: green7 
http://askubuntu.com/a/123304/42591
this is the guide i followed i think it works not sure completely but i think it does at least I do not get 10 same skype process running in the background but it feels works really sluggish and it crushed Empathy internet messenger 
so do you know any other ways to use skype under ubuntu or this is what I get