# Skype-wrapper Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04, skype

I am trying to get to work skype-wrapper on Ubuntu 15.04x64.

I followed [this steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/123304/445162) to install it on Ubuntu 15.04x64.
But this don't help me.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I'm trying to install skype-wrapper to integrate the skype with unity like [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-add-skype-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu). If there any other ways to integrate skype with unity I'll be very glad to hear about them.

Comment: Install the sni-qt package instead.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Why didn't those steps help you specifically?

Comment: I've already installed sni-qt package.  But it don't help integrating skype with unity.

Comment: I am getting this errors:
1) Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/skype-wrapper/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
2)Unable to locate package skype-wrapper

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`

Comment: As I said, I've already done this step. I've tried to do it again, but nothing changed.

Comment: I see. Typically it's sufficient - it's kind of 'the standard answer'. Did you relogin/reboot after having installed sni-qt:i386?

Comment: Yeah. And it also don't help.

Answer (score 0):

skype-wrapper has not been uploaded for vivid. You may want to open Software & Updates, switch to the Other Software tab, and edit the skype-wrapper entry by replacing "vivid" with "trusty".

Comment: I have another problem now. When I'm trying to launch skype-wrapper - nothing happens.
I am only able to start skype-wrapper settings.

Comment: @York's: Ok, I'm not able to help further. Maybe skype-wrapper wasn't uploaded to vivid for a reason - maybe it hasn't been updated to work with 15.04.